# get amount of cpu resources available inside docker container

Tags: linux, docker

From a docker container that was started with

```
$ docker run -it --memory=512 --cpus=1 farting_fairy /bin/bash
```

I want to retrieve the amount of CPU resources the container can use, from within the container.

Checking `/proc/cpuinfo` doesn't help because it lists all the CPUs from the host machine. Currently the only way I've come up with is doing something like

```
$ \time stress --cpu $(nproc) --timeout 10
```

and checking comparing the `%CPU` value. In the case of the docker container above it shouldn't show above 100% usage.

Comment: You're viewing the CPU % from 'docker stats'?

Comment: +Andy i need to view the available CPU from within the container.

Comment: I mean, when you were confirming the CPU scheduling wasn't working, how were you doing this? Docker containers use the host's kernel. You could set these values and make them available to the container. 

Maybe it's worth saying what you're ultimately wanting to achieve as there might be a better way.